# Android:Place Ad at bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to place ad banner at bottom of screen. I have written the following code which has one bug that whenever the listview content is too large when ad overrides the content and last element of listview is never visible . How can I code so that whenever the ads are not visible(because of any reason) then listview should occupy the whole screen and whenever ads are visible they should not override the last element of list view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_img"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/rhymesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your linear Layout add the following

```
android:layout_above="@+id/startAppBanner"
```

It will work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try Using this code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rlLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_img"
        tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

        <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
            android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/rhymesList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/startAppBanner"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
        </ListView>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may set"layout_above" as "startAppBanner" hopefully will with achieve that

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rhymesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```